# Creating Multiple Tables with the reference of existing tables but with different names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement where I need to create multiple tables with the help of some existing tables but the new tables would have some different names.

For example:

Existing Table Names:

```
INT_Employees,
INT_HumanResource,
INT_Payroll,
INT_Contacts etc..
```

New Tables should have prefix STG so it should look like:

```
STG_Employees,
STG_HumanResource,
STG_Payroll,
STG_Contacts etc..
```

Note: There are around 127 tables and we need to create new 127 tables with prefix STG_.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you need to copy the data, or just the structure of the table?

Comment: Hi Austin,Just the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to copy the table structure you can use select into with a where predicate that will prevent any rows from being returned.

```
select * into STG_Employees from INT_Employees where 1 = 0
```

Just repeat this for each table.

--EDIT--

Here is an example of you can leverage dynamic sql to do this task instead of resorting to loops. We simply use sys.tables to help us generate our sql statement.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''

select @sql = @sql + 'select * into ' + stuff(name, 1, 4, 'STG_') + ' from ' + name + ' where 1 = 0;'
from sys.tables 
where name like 'INT[_]%'

select @sql --once your comfortable the sql being generated is correct simply uncomment the next line
--exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Please note that if you want primary keys, indexes, foreign keys, computed columns etc you will need to generate those scripts another way. This will only generate the table structures.

Comment: Is there a way we can use a looping concept for all these tables ?

Comment: Why use looping? Do you have a list of all the tables?

Comment: Yeah, we can get it from sys.tables by using the Object_ID

Comment: OK. I have meeting here in a second but I can show you how we can leverage some dynamic sql for this and not use any loops. Give me an hour or so.

Comment: Be aware this method won't create any constraints, keys, indexes, identity property, or computed column definitions present in the source tables. Another option would be to script all the tables & run a find-replace on the script.

Comment: @GarethLyons it will pick up identity but you are spot on that the rest of these potentially very important pieces will be skipped.

Comment: @SeanLange cheers for the clarification. Would edit identity out if I could :)

Comment: Thanks Sean. It worked. For "constraints, keys, indexes, identity property, or computed column definitions present in the source tables" they would be taken care by some other systems.